# pass parameters to iframe

Tags: html, iframe

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/eticket/view.php?e=%email&t=%ticket"
 id="I1" name="I1" style="width: 759px; height: 824px"> </iframe>
```

Above iframe works as it is except that it's not using the passed parameters, because they are passed to a PHP code.

How can I pass the same parameters to this iframe?

Comment: This link will help you: http://forums.netobjects.com/showthread.php?11252-Is-it-possible-to-pass-a-parameter-to-an-iFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, please be informed that it is a good practice to always include code whenever we are talking about codes. It makes sense even though it is just an example. This way we can see that you are not just asking, but you are also working.

**Second**, please be more specific on your question. If you want specific answer, please supply us with specific questions.

**To answer you question** you can pass variable to iframe by means of url and using **GET** for a detailed instruction you can refer to [this](http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php) link. By passing variable through url you can get those variable in iframe, because iframes are another page of your website.

**Lastly**, I just want to welcome you to stackoverflow community. :)